# TypeError: cross_entropy_loss(): argument 'input' (position 1) must be Tensor, not tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-learning, pytorch

I am getting this error>> TypeError: cross_entropy_loss(): argument 'input' (position 1) must be Tensor, not tuple

I tried different ways to convert tuple into tensor, however I could not manage to solve the problem. could anyone help me please.

this is the config code that includes the main args_setting.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpgcF.png)

this is the training code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3Hah.png)

and this is the model of NN

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgjlP.png)

finally this is the error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0Qfz.png)

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want that those numbers of class_weights be a tensor, you should simply use a

```
class_weights = torch.tensor([0.02, 1.02])
```

I recommend you to see this [link](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor) to know about creating tensors